# Why does this size_t i = size variable giving "garbage" value when used in for loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, size-t

I have defined size as the passed value of 6 tracing the value of "size" also produced 6, however when I use size, or even plainly 6 to initialize i but in the for-loop, the value of i goes to garbage.
In the case here i just initialize the value of 6 for easier interpretation. To my best understanding, size_t is similar to an unsigned int or unsigned long int depending on the compiler

```
for (size_t i = 6 ; i >= 0; --i){
        printf("%lu\n",i);
    }
```

Comment: What unsigned number does *not* meet the condition `>= 0`?

Comment: Since `i >= 0` is always true, the loop never terminates.  And when you decrement an unsigned zero, it wraps around and you get the largest possible number of the type.  Perhaps you meant `i > 0` instead.

Comment: I had believed that the --i , would bring the i value to 0 after 6 iterations of the loop?

however, I see your point it'll never reach less than 0 . . .

Comment: yes it'll set the value to 0, but 0 is still larger than or equal to 0

Comment: Aside: With `size_t`, use `z` as in `printf("%zu\n",i);`

Comment: Consider the "arrow" operator: `for (size_t i = 6 ; i --> 0; ){`.  Hint: there is no `-->` operator.

Comment: I personally think the "arrow operator" is a pretty deceptive trick for someone if they're newer to any form of programming - not something I'd personally recommend to someone outside of the novelty of it. `i > 0` is perfectly acceptable/idiomatic here, and keeps the decrement seperate.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yeah either that or the magic shift zero towards zero operator `for (size_t*i=&(size_t){6}; --i<: 0:>>0 ;)`. Or if you prefer, the fancy arrow operator `i<:0 :>--> 0`. For we shall teach great practices to beginners...

Comment: @Rogue Yes, of course, better ot break the operators up: `for (size_t i = 6 ; i-- > 0; ){`.  Alas sometimes ones humor is too vague.

Answer (score 2):

`gcc -Wall -Wextra` called and said hi:

> warning: comparison of unsigned expression in '>= 0' is always true [-Wtype-limits]

Do yourself a favour and stop searching for bugs that the compiler already found, by following this advise: [What compiler options are recommended for beginners learning C?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/282565)

---

Now what happens in this case is that unsigned integers have well-defined wrap around. When going past 0, `size_t` will therefore get the value of a very large integer.

You then lie to `printf` and say that you are passing a `signed long`, when you are in fact passing an unsigned `size_t`. This is strictly speaking undefined behavior and anything can happen. The correct conversion specifier to use is `%zu`.

In practice on a system with 8 bit `long`, you might get an output such as
18446744073709551615, but this isn't guaranteed since it's a bug. In either case it is an eternal loop which will hang the program.

Answer (score 0):

i >= 0 is always true because i is a size_t and can't get under 0

So the loop won't terminate, this is something your compiler accepts or not depending your compilation options

If you decrement a size_t which is equal to 0, this size_t will get the largest possible value for size_t.

You can use i > 0 instead or use
`for(int i = 6;i >= 0;--i)`
if you want your 0 to be printed.

PS : %zu is for size_t and %d for int (or %i , %d being for decimal integer input)

Comment: Alternatively, `ssize_t` is a signed version of `size_t`, though I don't think it's standard or portable.

Comment: I didn't know about that, you can find it in "sys/types.h" library

Comment: `ssize_t` is POSIX, I think; use `ptrdiff_t`? Or just test after instead.

Comment: my class limits the keywords and data types we may use to what has been covered in the textbook up to this point. As well as for arrays, the proff. want's us to use size_t to form "good habits." Though I didn't understand why other than it will keep you from trying to enter a negative for the indices.
I settled for

         size_t i = SIZE; i >= 1

then for any code targeting i, i-1 was used.